# How to set ref of a Form Item inside a 'antd' Form in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

With similar approach able to get the desired refs in Form.Control when I am using react-bootstrap Form

But not getting the refs when using antd forms in ReactJS

```
<Form.Item>        
   <Input placeholder='Name' size='large'  ref="usernameref"  />
 </Form.Item>
```

not able to access this ref in other place like on button click of the button inside the form

The entire code below

```
import React from "react";
//import { Modal, Form ,Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { addUser, updateUser, loadoff, loadon} from "../actions/action.js";
import { Button, Form, Modal ,Input } from "antd";

class UserModalWindow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      update: this.props.update,
      rowindex: this.props.rowindextoupdate
    };
  }


  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return { rowindex: props.rowindextoupdate };
  }

  render() {
    async function wait(duration = 2000) {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, duration));
    }


    const layout = {
      labelCol: { span: 24 },
      wrapperCol: { span: 24 },
    };

    return (

      <Modal   {...this.props}  title="User Form" >

      <Form
      {...this.props}
      {...this.layout}
      name="basic"
      >
      <Form.Item
          label='Name'
          name='name'
          rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your name' }]}>

          <Input placeholder='Name' size='large'  ref="usernameref"  />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        label='Email'
        name='email'

        rules={[
          {
            type: 'email',
            message: 'The input is not valid mail.',
          },
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your mail id',
          },
        ]}>
        <Input placeholder='Email' size='large' ref="usermailref"/>
      </Form.Item>


      <Button  loading={this.props.loader.loading}  onClick = {async()=>
                        {
                            var obj = {}

                              obj.field1 = this.refs.usernameref.value ;  // here both the refs are undefined
                              obj.field2 = this.refs.usermailref.value;

                                console.log(this.refs)

                                this.props.loadon();
                                await wait();
                                this.props.loadoff();

                                if(this.state.update === 'true')
                                   {
                                       obj.index = this.state.rowindex.index ;
                                       this.props.updateUser(obj);
                                    }
                                else
                               {
                                console.log(obj)
                                this.props.addUser(obj);
                               }

                                this.props.onHide();

                        }}
                        > Save</Button>

    </Form>
    </Modal>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    loader: state.loader
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ addUser, updateUser, loadon, loadoff }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UserModalWindow);
```

But using React-bootstrap  Forms  works as desired
What might be the reason? Do I need to use DecoratorField?

Comment: Check this. This one helped me in similar case
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/6189

Answer (score -1):

You should give ref to Form tag
please follow these instructions

1)create ref like this
`formRef = React.createRef()`;
2)use this ref in the form tag like this
 `<Form ref={this.formRef} name="control-ref">code goes here.........</Form>`

Than you can use this ref,you can also check antd documentation how it will work https://ant.design/components/form/
please reply to this thread if you are facing the issue or find it helpfull